# How to spy on an Angular filter using Karma and Sinon

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner, sinon

If I have a service and filter like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])

.filter('myFilter', [function() {
    return function() { return 1; };
}])

.service('myServiceWhichCallsMyFilter', ['$filter', function($filter) {
    this.callTheFilter = $filter('myFilter');
}]);
```

and tests like this:

```
describe('myFilterTest', function() {
    var $filter;

    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function (_$filter_) {
        $filter = _$filter_;
    }));

    it('should filter correctly', function() {
        var filteredValue = $filter('myFilter')(100);
        expect(filteredValue).to.equal(1); // passes
    });
});

describe('myServiceTest', function() {
    var myServiceWhichCallsMyFilter;
    var myFilterSpy = sinon.spy();

    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    beforeEach(module(function ($provide) {
        $provide.value('myFilter', myFilterSpy);
    }));

    beforeEach(inject(function (_myServiceWhichCallsMyFilter_) {
        myServiceWhichCallsMyFilter = _myServiceWhichCallsMyFilter_;
    }));

    it('should call myFilter', function() {
        myServiceWhichCallsMyFilter.callTheFilter();
        expect(myFilterSpy.callCount).to.equal(1); // fails - callCount is 0
    });
});
```

...how can I get the second test to pass?  Within that test, I am only interested in whether or not the service is calling the filter (not in the correctness of the filter, which I test separately), so I want to mock it.  But `$provide.value('myFilter', myFilterSpy)` does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it: in the second test I need to `$provide` my spy filter under the name of `myFilterFilter`:

```
describe('myServiceTest', function() {
    var myServiceWhichCallsMyFilter;
    var myFilterSpy  = sinon.spy();

    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    beforeEach(module(function ($provide) {
        $provide.value('myFilterFilter', myFilterSpy );
    }));

    beforeEach(inject(function (_myServiceWhichCallsMyFilter_) {
        myServiceWhichCallsMyFilter = _myServiceWhichCallsMyFilter_;
    }));

    it('should call myFilter', function() {
        expect(myFilterSpy.callCount).to.equal(0); // callTheFilter has not been called!
        myServiceWhichCallsMyFilter.callTheFilter();
        expect(myFilterSpy.callCount).to.equal(1); // passes
    });
});
```

This is actually mentioned in the docs: ["Notice that the suffix 'Filter' is appended to your filter name when injected"](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09#test).

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('myApp', [])

.filter('myFilter', [function() {
    return function() { return 1; };
}])

.service('myServiceWhichCallsMyFilter', ['$filter', function($filter) {
    this.callTheFilter = $filter('myFilter');
}]);
```

See, your service actually isn't calling the $filter, it's just instantiating it.

Change the line as follows and your test will 'pass', although you're changing the behavior so... figure out what you want it to do

```
this.callTheFilter = $filter('myFilter')(100);
```

Comment: No, the test doesn't pass if I make that change. It errors out on `myServiceWhichCallsMyFilter.callTheFilter()` because `callTheFilter` will have been been assigned to the result of the filter function: 1, which is not itself a function. I don't want the service to call the filter; I want it to expose a function which calls the filter.  And then I want to test whether calling that function will call the filter.